# Force Heroku-based Wordpress Onto Port 80 Using Nginx on Heroku

Tags: wordpress, heroku, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running a Heroku app utilizing Nginx to reverse proxy to another heroku app that runs Wordpress.

Nginx Buildpack: https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack
Wordpress Heroku template starting point: https://github.com/xyu/heroku-wp

Here is the Nginx configuration for the server and reverse proxy:

```
  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    location /locations/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host [wordpress-app].herokuapp.com;
      proxy_pass http://[wordpress-app].herokuapp.com/locations/;
      proxy_redirect default;
    }
  }
```

The reverse proxy works in most cases except when Worpdress does a redirect.

If I visit `[rails_app].herokuapp.com/locations/location1`, it tries to reverse proxy `[wordpress_app].herokuapp.com/locations/location1`. However, Wordpress will redirect this URL to `[wordpress_app].herokuapp.com/locations/location1/` (append a trailing '/').
When Wordpress redirects, Nginx tries to redirect to `[rails_app].herokuapp.com:[portnumber]/locations/location1` where the port number is the dyno port. In this situation, I  do not want the port inserted into the URL because it creates a bad address.

I believe the problem can be solved by modifying the Nginx configuration but I have had no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add `port_in_redirect off;` to the server configuration. For example:

```
 server {
    port_in-redirect off;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @moohkooh Can you post your whole nginx file?

Comment: i created a new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586218/heroku-nginx-on-port-80